# How can I limit the number of lines shown on the homepage of a Jekyll blog?

Tags: jekyll, liquid, jekyll-theme

In my Jekyll theme, some of my blog posts are shown as it is on the home page. But I want to limit them up to certain lines. That is, I want to show only 5-6 lines of the blog on the home page. 
For example,
[image]
In, 
**1.** 5 lines of the blog post are visible 
**2.** Only two lines of the blog post are visible 
**3.** In the last post of the **page** the entire blog post is visible on the homepage.

I am new to Jekyll and I don't know how can I do that. The theme I am using is the earlier version of [White Paper](https://github.com/vinitkumar/white-paper)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The preview text from each blog posts are from `{{ post.excerpt }}` in `index.html`[1].  It looks like the White Paper jekyll theme is using the default behavior of Post excerpts[2].

> By default this is the first paragraph of content in the post, however
>   it can be customized by setting a excerpt_separator variable in front
>   matter or _config.yml.

If you want to control how much text is previewed for each blog post, you can stop using `{{ post.excerpt }}` and do something like `{{ post.content | truncatewords: 60 }}` instead.

These `{{ ... }}` code snippets are from the Liquid templating language [3][4]

[1] https://github.com/vinitkumar/white-paper/blob/3995398d74b42ee70ad2e4c82a0ab8955ad49955/index.html#L10

[2] https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts

[3] https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/

[4] https://shopify.github.io/liquid/

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked @Kin but not for every posts, I can still see the previous posts completely on the home page!

Answer (score -1):

If you'd like to have more variation in excerpt size by each post, you can also use an excerpt-separator anywhere you'd like in the body of your posts [1].

> By default this is the first paragraph of content in the post, however
>   it can be customized by setting a `excerpt_separator` variable in front
>   matter or `_config.yml`

[1] https://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/#post-excerpts